# Limit on DQL Subquery Without Query Builder

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine-orm

Can I limit in a subquery without using query builder? 
Example:

```
$results = $em->createQuery('
    SELECT d
    FROM FLIContractBundle:DieselPrice d
    WHERE d.date = (
        SELECT p.date
        FROM FLIContractBundle:DieselPrice p
        ORDER BY p.date DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
')->getResult();
```

Comment: can you not call `setMaxResults()` before you call `getResult()`?

Comment: Not on the subquery, I can't.

Comment: you could try `MAX(p.date)`. Im not sure if thats a valid DQL function tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT d
FROM FLIContractBundle:DieselPrice d
WHERE d.date = (
    SELECT max(p.date)
    FROM FLIContractBundle:DieselPrice p
)
```

Comment: That works for this query, but the answer to my question is, "you can't".

Comment: @Ascherer The time difference from my answer to your comment is less than one minute. I didn't see it. And your answer is wrong in that an `order by` with a `max` makes no sense since the result is one only row. BTW your answer is two minutes later than mine making you the thief. And I was not the one who downvoted it.

Comment: My answer is gone, and i realize the order by, but non-the-less. Your answer came after my comment, and only you downvoted it. Kinda hard to steal from my own comment.

Comment: I downvoted it because you left the order by in the subquery, actually.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be to use a [Native Query](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) if you want a single query.